# Does full trust mean the same as Run As Administrator

Tags: privileges, administrator, full-trust

Does full trust mean the same as Run As Administrator?  I have read things stating that "for this to work, the application must be a full-trust application."  Is that the same as you must have administrator privileges to run the application?  If not, what's the difference?  How can you tell if an app is "full-trust"?

I am told that "Administrator or not, .Net apps won't do certain things if they aren't running from a 'trusted' location."  What is a "trusted location"?  If you run an app from a "trusted location", can you do things that "require full-trust" without being an administrator?

Answer (score 17):

No.  Full-trust is a .NET term used to indicate that it's not running in a reduced-priviledge .NET sandbox.  In .NET prior to 3.5 SP1, this included running from a network share (in the default configuration).  It also includes running as a ClickOnce application that has not requested additional permissions, or in some other browser-based sandbox.

Full-trust means it can do anything the user it is running as can do, not that is running as an administrator.

Answer (score 5):

No.  As of version 2.0, the .Net framework has it's own little filesystem setup for security.  Administrator or not, .Net apps won't do certain things if they aren't running from a 'trusted' location.

Just about anything on your local hard drive is trusted, but (and supposedly they fixed this for 3.5sp1) even the local intranet is *not* trusted, so most .Net desktop apps will fail to even start if they're sitting on a network drive or share.

You can change the configuration on a machine so it will allow apps from that zone, but it has to be done for *every* machine that's going to run the application, which breaks a common corporate deployment scenario.

From an ASP.Net standpoint, it also means that certain activities require more 'trust' than others.  Sending e-mail, for example, can cause exceptions if not set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Full Trust means that the C# code has total control over the current (.Net) process and all processes running under the Application Pool account.

It is the same as running a C++ dll

Admin access will depend on the IIS settings (ie. if you run the website under System or an admin account)