# The Application Requires Full Trust Assembly Office Application

Tags: .net, assemblies, full-trust

I am running the following code which tries to access a custom assembly.

```
MySection sec = (MySection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ColorReader");
```

The above line throws various exceptions which are listed below:

> The application requires full trust permissions to run correctly.
>   When deploying an office solution check to make sure you have fulfilled all the necessary security requirements. 
>   Use a certificate to obtain the required permissions.
>   If an assembly implementing the custom security object references other assemblies, add the referenced assemblies to the full trust assembly list.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Where is this code deployed?

Comment: The code is deployed to my development machine.

Comment: In what kind of solution? ASP.NET? As an Office add-in? If so, what version?

Comment: It is a console application and the error occurs when I am executing the above line.

Comment: Is the application running on your local machine or from a network drive? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102282/does-full-trust-mean-the-same-as-run-as-administrator.